# Velocidad para listar gran cantidad de registros con SpringJPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data

Estoy desarrollando un sistema con SpringMVC, Angular 7 y la DB con MySQL.

En mi desarrollo hay 2 tablas que tienen 70.000 registros aproximadamente y varias relaciones, el tema es que si listo todos los registros de esas tablas(lo uso para mostrarlos en un ng-select) tarda mucho en recuperar los registros(mas de 10 segundos), pude solucionar el tema de velocidad con un "nativeQuery" en el repository, pero tengo que convertir el resultado en el objeto despues y me lleva mucho tiempo y la consulta o nativeQuery se me hace muy largo!!!

Necesitaria saber si hay alguna forma de recuperar como objeto y algun query que me ayude con la velocidad de recuperacion de registros y me los devuelva como objetos, no como datos crudos(como el nativeQuery)

Comment: Si es para mostrar los registros, un usuario jamas vera 70.000 registros al tiempo por lo que te recomiendo usar paginacion del lado de spring y en angular por medio de un evento de scroll si es por desplazamiento o una barra de navegación solicites mas elementos, incluso si pones en el navegador tanta info el usuario tendrá problemas ya que la pagina se hace pesada, por lo que deberías agregar elementos a medida que avance el usuario y eliminar los anteriores. Para no complicarte mucho con la paginacion puedes crear un repositorio que extienda de PagingAndSortingRepository y seguir las instru

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo estuve utilizando, peor quería saber alguna otra forma, pero voy a tener que utilizar la paginacion en definitiva es la mejor opción para estos casos